# Can we get the Size of each page of Pdf using Php?

Tags: php, pdf

Can we get the size of each page of pdf using php?
Any function in php to get the page wise size of pdf?

Comment: Are you using any library?

Comment: @Sougata yes i am using pdf.js library

Comment: Googling this question yields about 88 million results using about 10.000 libraries. Can you briefly summarise why those results didn't help you when you read through them?

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche I need to load a pdf on website chunk by chunk.. The problem is that the calling $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'] gives asynchronous chunks.. due to which some pages never loads. So i thought to load the pdf page by page. Thats why i need to find page size of each page dynamically.

Comment: Then it would be good if you clarified your question, as it is written now you're not going to get decent answers. I'm not even sure I understand what your question is still: do you want to figure out which byte ranges in a PDF file contain the information for a specific page?

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche ok. let me clarify it.. my problem is that i want to display pdf on my website. Now i want that the whole size of pdf do not get loaded on the at once. I want that the pdf should be broken into some parts or chunks and and i should be able to request for those parts of pdf from client side synchronously so that the user may be able to see the initial parts of pdf while remaining part of pdf gets loaded on background in case the size of pdf is big say 15 MB. And i am using pdf.js library for it. Hope u understand the question

Comment: By the good question @ImVishal

Answer (score 1):

OK, after reading the comments, let me clarify that "the size of the page" completely isn't what this question is about. With that phrase, normally one refers to the size of the printed pages, such as "A4" or "Letter".

This instead, is about finding the byte ranges for all objects belonging to a particular page; in other words, how does one figure out which part of the file to read to display that page.

The answer is, that in generic PDF you can figure that out but it isn't going to help you. PDF uses a cross reference table to keep the location of each object in the file, but the objects used by a particular page (the page object itself, its content stream, the fonts, images, etc it uses, can be spread out over the file).

The only exception is when your PDF file is web-optimised (also called linearised). In that case the objects for the first page are in the file first, and a small cross reference table at the beginning of the file lists only those objects for the first page, allowing quick download of the byte range for the first page. This allows quick display of the first page while the rest of the file is still loading.

To know more about this, read the section called "Linearized PDF" (Annex F) of the PDF specification (ISO 32000-1, also available from the Adobe web site).

Comment: Can you give the conclusion of you big explanation? Means Is it possible by the php or not?

Comment: In what way is my answer not clear? It says exactly what is possible and not. Whether you’re using PHP or not is irrelevant.